# Расширение Chrome и как встроить текстовое поле в определенную страницу

Tags: javascript, html

Возник вопрос, необходимо встраивать textarea и кнопку скрипта с копированием написанного в данном текстовом поле на определённую страницу, сам вопрос как это сделать. Пользователи все устанавливают расширение для работы и собственно хотелось бы встроить это туда.
Я понимаю что должен быть быт скрипт который должен менять DOM, но вопрос какой.

Comment: Расширение tampermonkey посмотри..